# "Kindern", dative plural - What other words reflect that flexion in the plural form

Tags: grammatical-case, declension

I practice German cases sentences to learn by heart, but I have stumbled across a form that *I* don't think it is so common.

> Ich sprach mit den kleinen **Kindern**.

In this sentence, the plural form of *Kind* reflects the case with an *n*.
I don't think I have seen so many *n* at the end of words in plural dative.

But if it is to happen with a limited set of words, could you you give me some kind of rule to know which words get an *n* at the dative plural?

What I guess more or less, it's that plural in *er* should append and *n*. Is it all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All plural nouns that do not end in -n or -s gain an -n ending in the dative case.

Answer (score 7):

Look at german wikipedia:

> **Dativ-n**
>   Bei Wörtern, die im Nominativ Plural auf -e, -el und -er enden, wird im Dativ Plural ein -n angehängt. Diese Konstruktion ist im Hochdeutschen üblich, in manchen deutschen Mundarten und in der dialektnahen Umgangssprache fällt es allerdings oft weg.

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ#Dativ-n